# Ionic / Apache Cordova - HTTP requests best practices

Tags: angularjs, cordova, rest, http, ionic-framework

i'm developping an app with the ionic framework and a jee + postgresql backend.

I'm actually doubting about the HTTP Requests :

Should i use only **jsonp**? Or add an **Access-Control-Allow-Origin *** in my HTTP headers ?

Of course, both of these solutions are working, the second solution seems unsecure to me but i'm not use to mobile requests (without domain-based call/endpoint) so i don't really know what to choose ... i might also miss some other way to do the job ....

Do somebody know how to properly build this kind of communication ?

Thanks you !

Comment: If the requested resource supports CORS, you should not need to set access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be very flexible and very secure, you might want to implement a [JSON Web Token](http://jwt.io) solution. The server issues json web tokens to your users. You can define who gets a token. Then the token must be attached to every request from ionic to your server. The server determines what data to return, if the user is authorized.

For JEE there is [this package](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt). For ionic the [auth0](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-ionic/tree/master/examples/refresh-token-sample/www/lib/angular-jwt) repositories are a good study start. You can find many examples online. I think that is the most elaborate solution available, despite might not be easiest to implement.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look :)

Comment: Your solution is about securing communication between two sides using a token based auth, but i'll always need to Access-Control-Allow-Origin to all ?